# C++ Builder XE2, TXMLDocument 'DTD is prohibited'

Tags: vcl, c++builder-xe2, dtd, txmldocument, xml

When I try to read an XML document (eagle file) with an DTD I get the error:

> Project xx raised exception class EDOMParserError with message 'DTD is
>   prohibited'

The XML header looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE eagle SYSTEM "eagle.dtd">
```

If I remove the second line...

```
<!DOCTYPE eagle SYSTEM "eagle.dtd">
```

...everything works fine.

After some googling it seems like the MSXML parser have an option called ´prohibitDTD´ set to **true** by default (in earlier versions it was false).

However it seems not possible to set this option to false from the TXMLDocument class. One solution seems to be a recompile of the .pas library or to create the interface on my own with CoCreateInstance().

All examples I have seen out there are in Delphi and I'm having dificulties to trasnlate these to C++ Builder.

Does anyone know how to read a DTD XML document with C++ Builder XE2?

My example code...

```
#include <xmldoc.hpp>

_di_IXMLNode XMLObject;

TXMLDocument *XMLDocument = new TXMLDocument(this);
XMLDocument->LoadFromFile(fileName); // <----- Exception EDOMParserError
XMLObject = XMLDocument->DocumentElement;
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XE2 introduced a native solution to this very problem: there is a global `bool` variable named [`MSXML6_ProhibitDTD`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.Win.msxmldom.MSXML6_ProhibitDTD) declared in `Xml.Win.msxmldom.hpp`.  You can set it to `false` before loading data into `TXMLDocument`:

```
#include <xmldoc.hpp>
#include <msxmldom.hpp>

MSXML6_ProhibitDTD = false;
TXMLDocument *XMLDocument = new TXMLDocument(this):
XMLDocument->LoadFromFile(fileName);
_di_IXMLNode XMLObject = XMLDocument->DocumentElement;
```

On a side note: it is generally not a good idea to create `TXMLDocument` instances dynamically like this. It is better to use the `IXMLDocument` interface instead:

```
#include <xmldoc.hpp>
#include <msxmldom.hpp>

MSXML6_ProhibitDTD = false;
_di_IXMLDocument XMLDocument = LoadXMLDocument(fileName);
_di_IXMLNode XMLObject = XMLDocument->DocumentElement;
```

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm! Strange that this very piece of information should be so hard to find... Why is IXMLDocument better than TXMLDocument? As I understood, IXMLDocument is a part of TXMLDocument.

Comment: `TXMLDocument` implements the `IXMLDocument` interface, so it has the same functionality. However, if you dynamically instantiate `TXMLDocument` with a `NULL` Owner (which you should do when creating short-lived XML objects), it acts as a reference-counted object. This is documented behavior. It is not safe to assign a dynamic instance of `TXMLDocument` to a `TXMLDocument*` variable unless it has an Owner assigned. Otherwise, you have to assign it to a `_di_IXMLDocument` variable instead to maintain the reference count correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In my case the dynamic instance of TXMLDocument* always have an owner and lives through the whole application. I have earlier project code working with TXMLDocument, so I use it out of convenience to reuse the old code.

Answer (score 1):

Since the workaround with the global variable `MSXML6_ProhibitDTD` is deprecated and I couldn't get it to work with XE5 either, here is another solution:

As stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Xml.Win.msxmldom.TMSXMLDOMDocumentFactory.AddDOMProperty), there is this method to change the DOM property

```
Xml.Win.Msxmldom.MSXMLDOMDocumentFactory.AddDOMProperty
```

Unfortunately it's not so trivial to use this...

include the header for this namespace:

```
#include <Xml.Win.msxmldom.hpp>

Foo::Foo()
{
     //change the dom property in your constructor.
    ((TMSXMLDOMDocumentFactory*)Xml::Win::Msxmldom::MSXMLDOMDocumentFactory)->AddDOMProperty("ProhibitDTD", False, true);
}
```

and access this method. (The cast is necessary, because the `MSXMLDOMDocumentFactory` itself is inherited from a metaclass interface or so. I don't got the concept behind.)

inspired from a delphi blog: https://bobsotherblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/fixing-dtd-is-prohibited-error-in-delphi/

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy MSXMLDOM.pas into your project folder, and modify it in order to fix this issue.

Change the implementation of `function TMSDOMDocument.GetMSDocument` to the following, and then rebuild your project.

Note you have to use `IXMLDOMDocument2.setProperty` instead of accessing `ProhibitDTD` directly, as `IXMLDOMDocument2` doesn't publish `ProhibitDTD`.

```
function TMSDOMDocument.GetMSDocument: IXMLDOMDocument;
var
  Doc2: IXMLDOMDocument2;
begin
  Result := MSNode as IXMLDOMDocument;
  if Supports(Result, IXMLDOMDocument2, Doc2) then
      Doc2.setProperty('ProhibitDTD', False);
end;
```

Note that this will only work if you're *not* building with runtime packages!

This solution is from an Embarcadero forums post made by a member of TeamB; I remembered reading it, and found it in a search of those forums via [CodeNewsFast](http://codenewsfast.com) - search functionality at the EMBT forums hasn't ever worked well, and a recent rebuild or reindex or something has made it even worse than before. :-)

Comment: I am the TeamB member who discussed this workaround in the EMBT forums. This workaround is only needed in XE and earlier. XE2 introduced a native solution to this exact problem. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, @Remy. I know. That's why I posted the link to the search that I got it from; so people would know I wasn't taking credit for coming up with the solution. :-)